# Distributed Setup. Different scenario on one system

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

My apologies if i may be reposting a problem which may already have been
addressed here.
But i was not not able to find a proper answer to my problem.

I am setting up JMETER in distributed mode across 10 different systems,
using OS process handler in a thread group.
The purpose is to invoke a executable and generate load for a server.

around 200 parallel executions are required on each system for a time frame
with ramp and down.
I have all this figured out thanks to quite an elaborate support forum and
documentation.

But out of these 10 systems, 1 specific system needs to run 50 parallel
executables and with some different parameters.

How can i select/force one specific system to do a different operation that
other 9 systems?

Please guide.

Regards
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

If you know the machine name / ip in which you want to change the load, you can use User Defined Variables.

[image]

MachineA, MachineB.. are the names of the slave machines in which you are planning to run your jmeter test.

Then, you can get machine specific details by using

```
${__evalVar(${this.machine.users})}
```

If you use the expression in the No of threads in the ThreadGroup as given below, depends on the slave , for the same test, it puts different loads.

[image]

This is just an example. But similar approach should solve your issue.